# Algorithm to push/insert to stack

Tags: c, stack

Newbie to C here and following online book tutorials. (I have been attempting linked-lists but little complex for now, will return to these later.) I have the following algorithm:

```
Algorithm: PUSH (STACK, ITEM)
[STACK is an array of MAXSIZE and ITEM is an item to be pushed onto
stack]
1. [Check for stack overflow]
If TOP = MAXSIZE - 1 then
a) Print: Overflow
b) Return
2. [Increase top by 1]
Set TOP = TOP + 1
3. [Insert item in new top position]
Set STACK[TOP] = ITEM
4. Return
```

However, I cannot understand step 1, for `Top`, how would I go about initialising this, because `Top` should indicate some pre-existing value? For example:

(My attempt)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int push(int item, int(*stack)[item]){
    int top;
    if(top == sizeof(*stack)/sizeof(*stack[0])-1){
        printf("Overflow");
        return -1;
    }
    top++;
    *stack[top] = item;
    return **stack;
}

int main(void){
    int arr[4] = {0 , 1, 2, 3};
    int itm = 2;
    int result;
    result = push(itm, &arr);
    printf("\nResult: %i", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Would always produce an overflow

Comment: `TOP` is like a counter of elements currently on the stack. To be more precise it seems to be the array index of the last valid element. That's why it's incremented by one whenever you push a new element. And that's why you are only allowed to go to `MAXSIZE - 1` cause that's the last element in the array, i.e. you have used all array elements and can't push further elements to the array

Comment: OT: Are you aware that `sizeof(*stack)/sizeof(*stack[0])` will be the same as `item`? I guess not because it does make much sense...

Comment: `int top; if(top == ...` uses an uninitialized variable. That cannot work. Also `*stack[top] = item;` should be `(*stack)[top] = item;`.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Did not know this, so what's the correct way to initialise this inside the function `push`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will simply need to store the current value of top and send it along with the stack everywhere. You should define a struct, like so:

```c
typedef struct Stack {
    int stack[16]; // Replace 16 with desired capacity.
    int top;
} Stack;
```

Create a new stack like this:

```c
Stack s = { .top = -1 };
```

Now all your functions should receive a pointer to this stack, and functions like push should update the value of top.

Comment: This is for sure a step in a much better direction, A little nitpick. Avoid hard coding of array size. Instead use a define like `#define MAXSIZE 16` and use `int stack[MAXSIZE];`. The array size will be used in other code, e.g. the `push` function, so it's better to avoid writing 16 several places in the code

Comment: I cannot successfully understand linked lists yet. For example, I can build structs and functions, however, I have not attempted them inside `main`. I'm sure its very simple, but I'll have to read into it some more.

Comment: @Emil11 But my suggestion is not a linked list. It's an array like in your solution, just inside a struct so you can easily couple it with `top` wherever you send it.